# Solution to definite integration by substitution different when pulling out a constant (C4 Edexcel June 2013 Q5(b))

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, substitution

The solution to definite integration appears to be different when pulling out a constant. I am not sure why. Can anyone explain?
(Integration by Substitution : Core Maths : C4 Edexcel June 2013 Q5(b))

[image: Integration by Substitution : Core Maths : C4 Edexcel June 2013 Q5(a) : ExamSolutions]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your error occurs when integrating $\frac{2}{2u-1},$ using another substitution $v = 2u-1$ will give you $\int \frac{dv}{v}$ so you'll get the result $\ln(2u - 1),$ where your answer has an extra $2$

Comment: Thank you. Why can't the constant be pulled out of the integral of 2/(2u-1)?

Comment: It can, but you would need another $\frac12$ in the integral to deal with the change of variables so they would cancel out.